# Boot SOMETIMES stuck in the grub

Tags: boot, grub2

[Grub Fail](https://youtu.be/rqm8o8cMxhE)

My ubuntu has been booting like this since the first install but after some 20 seconds of shenanigan, it booted to system. But lately I stuck at this particular loading thing. Tried recovery mode, no help at all.
Any thoughts.

Comment: See my partial answer. Are you able to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: Yes I can. I tried to fix the issue from there but no help.

Answer (score 1):

**First things first, we need to check your file system.**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**You have a very old BIOS...**

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` shows that your current BIOS is version 1.10 from 2013.

```
Toshiba Satellite L50-A
PSKL8L-006002
```

The latest version can be downloaded at https://support.dynabook.com.

Please update your BIOS and see if it helps.

Comment: from sudo fdisk -l, I got this 

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8a0d65e7

Comment: @ThePilot as you can see, posting some info into comments doesn't work... you need to edit your original question, copy/paste the text into your question, and then format it with the {} icon.

Comment: sry sir newbie here

Comment: @ThePilot status please...

Comment: Problem remains the same. I previously used 16.04 lts and changed it to 18.04 lts and I wonder, if this new kernel might not support my 6 year old laptop. It probably less likely.

Comment: @ThePilot Were you ever able to complete my answer? Your first (incomplete) comment was never edited into your question, so I don't know what you were trying to ask me or tell me. Did the screen full of text occur in 16.04? Did 18.04 ever boot properly for you? Give me the exact make/model # of your computer, and the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: I didn't have this problem with 16.04.

Comment: for dmidecode I received this,'1.10'

Comment: @ThePilot I need the make/model # of your computer, so that I can go look for a newer BIOS.

Comment: Sorry for very late replay sir. I caught in the middle of something. 
Make is Toshiba
Model - Satellite L50-A.
I think issue could be in kernel not supporting the old specs or hardware.

Comment: @ThePilot please see the update in my answer. Please remember to accept it if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: So in order to do that i have to use a virtual machine like Wine or PlayonLinux right? I ll update you. Thanks for sticking up with this issue.

Comment: Sir, in dmicode my PSK is this : PSKL8L-006002.
Surprising thing is that even dynobook bios search did show any result on that particular model. Like this was never existed.

Comment: @ThePilot lets try searching their site by serial #. Also, does your computer still do what your video shows? Can you get to Recovery Mode? If so, what happens if you select the oldest kernel that is shown? Does it boot properly then?

Comment: Yes I can get to the recovery mode but there weren't many options of different kernel versions showing.

Comment: @ThePilot Did you try one of the older kernels? You did fsck, yes? Have you found your serial # and gone back to dynabook site to search?

Comment: Yes I did find my serial number sir. But dynobook didn't offer any updates for that particular sn

Comment: @ThePilot I would contact the support staff at dynabook.com to see if they know what BIOS update to use for your model #.

Comment: Thanks you sir you are very much indeed a help for me. Thank you again.